# How can I extract as many rows as I want from the result rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to extract by limiting the number of rows that meet the condition to n in the result row

There are tow tables

```
tb_info
--------------------------
 id(PK) | number | status |
--------------------------
    1   |    1   |    A   |
    2   |    1   |    B   |
    3   |    2   |    B   |
    4   |    2   |    A   |
    5   |    3   |    B   |
    6   |    3   |    A   |
    7   |    4   |    C   |
    8   |    4   |    A   |
    9   |    5   |    C   |
   10   |    6   |    A   |


tb_status
---------------------
 st_id(PK) | status 
---------------------
     1     |    A   
     2     |    B   
     3     |    C
```

Then run the query to get the following result:

```sql
SELECT id, number, status
FROM tb_info
WHERE number <= 5
ORDER BY id

--------------------------
 id | number | status |
--------------------------
  1 |    1   |    A   |
  2 |    1   |    B   |
  3 |    2   |    B   |
  4 |    2   |    A   |
  5 |    3   |    B   |
  6 |    3   |    A   |
  7 |    4   |    C   |
  8 |    4   |    A   |
  9 |    5   |    C   |
```

I want to get the two rows with the lowest number for each status value in tb_status in this result table.

The result I want to achieve is shown in the table below

```
--------------------------
 id | number | status |
--------------------------
  1 |    1   |    A   |
  4 |    2   |    A   |
  2 |    1   |    B   |
  3 |    2   |    B   |
  7 |    4   |    C   |
  9 |    5   |    C   |
```

No matter how much I think about it, the answer does not come up. What should I do?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon mysql version is 5.7.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more the less the same solution as @forpas with the inclusion of tb_status

```
drop table if exists tb_info,tb_status;
create table tb_info
(id int primary key, number int, status varchar(1));
insert into tb_info values
(    1   ,    1   ,    'A'   ),
(    2   ,    1   ,    'B'   ),
(    3   ,    2   ,    'B'   ),
(    4   ,    2   ,    'A'   ),
(    5   ,    3   ,    'B'   ),
(    6   ,    3   ,    'A'   ),
(    7   ,    4   ,    'C'   ),
(    8   ,    4   ,    'A'   ),
(    9   ,    5   ,    'C'   ),
(   10   ,    6   ,    'A'   ),
(   11   ,    1   ,    'd'   ),
(   12   ,    3   ,    'd'   );

create table tb_status
( st_id int primary key, status varchar(1)); 

insert into tb_status values
(     1     ,    'A'),   
(     2     ,    'B'), 
(     3     ,    'C');

select s.id,s.number,s.status
from tb_status
join
(select t.id,t.number,t.status,
        if(t.`status` <> @p , @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=t.`status` p
from tb_info t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by t.status,t.number 
) s
on s.status = tb_status.status  
where s.rn <= 2
order by s.status,s.rn;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | number | status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 | A      |
|  4 |      2 | A      |
|  2 |      1 | B      |
|  3 |      2 | B      |
|  7 |      4 | C      |
|  9 |      5 | C      |
+----+--------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note d is dropped.

Comment: (For versions prior to 8.0) https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4bACa7oRuKCyS6uEbqPZJQ/0 - note I've added a little '+0' to avoid an implicit casting error.

Comment: @Strawberry true and user has stated in comments that version is 5.7.27

Comment: It could still be reworked for compatibility with both 5.7 and 8.0 (by reorganising a little), but of course there are simpler methods available in 8.0

Comment: @Strawberry  Adding +0 restricts the status of the result to one case.

Comment: @P.Salmon 
I realized that there are different solutions for different versions. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @KimBenGon Not quite; I'm simply demonstrating that (as written), this solution won't work in 8.0

Comment: @Strawberry i See. Your feedback has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables to rank the numbers of every status:

```
SET @rn := 0;
SET @status := '';
SELECT id, number, `status` FROM (
  SELECT @rn := CASE 
    WHEN @status = `status` THEN @rn + 1 
    ELSE 1
  END AS rn, number, `status`, id,
  @status := `status`   
  FROM tb_info 
  WHERE number <= 5
  ORDER BY `status`, number 
) t
WHERE rn <= 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpA36HJZpF8ojWT7fqHAjt/1).
Results:

```
| id  | number | status |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | 1      | A      |
| 4   | 2      | A      |
| 2   | 1      | B      |
| 3   | 2      | B      |
| 7   | 4      | C      |
| 9   | 5      | C      |
```

Comment: Thank you for your sincere answer to my question. I have applied your answer as a test code and have studied a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to order the results by status column so

```
SELECT id, number, status FROM tb_info WHERE number <= 5 ORDER BY id, status
```

or just

```
SELECT id, number, status FROM tb_info WHERE number <= 5 ORDER BY status
```

should do

Comment: Not the result. I want I want to get 2 rows out of the rows that satisfy the desired conditions

Comment: what does this output?

Comment: Your answer is included in my question. 
I want to make A, B, and C of the status column print 2 outputs each.